# LINQ to MySql Data Provider

Tags: .net, mysql, linq, linq-to-sql

After a quick Google I couldn’t find anything too promising so I was wondering if anyone knew if there is a good/widely used LINQ to MySql Data Provider out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist.  There is currently a project called DBLinq as part of the Mono Olive project to add support for other providers, but currently the only server that works is Microsoft's SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, that confirms my findings on google also. cheers

Answer (score 0):

We offer MySQL-specific implementation of the LINQ to SQL tecnology. 
Check out its features [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/linq.html).

Comment: I thought product advertising was not allowed?